# How to show the uikit modal on top of the uikit modal in mvc4 using jquery ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, uikit

I have been stuck in a problem since couple of days.

**I am trying to get the UIKIT Modal on the top of another UIKIT modal.**

I have an EditModal and SubEditModal as follows:

```
<div id="modalEdit" class="uk-modal">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-animation-scale-up">
            <div class="modalTitle"><h1>Edit</h1></div>
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modalSubEdit" class="uk-modal">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-animation-scale-up">
                <div class="modalTitle"><h1>Edit</h1></div>
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have address listing in modalEdit. When the user clicks on edit in one of address, I use the modalSubEdit to display the edit form. This should be displayed on the top of modalEdit. I wrote the following jquery:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
        var container = $('#modalEdit .uk-modal-dialog');
        var targetDiv = $('#modalSubEdit .uk-modal-dialog');
        targetDiv.empty();
        targetDiv.append(data);
        container.add(targetDiv);
});
```

**The problem is as soon as the modalSubEdit is displayed, modalEdit closes itself. When I dig deep into it, I found that, as soon as modalSubEdit is displayed, the display property of modalEdit is set to none.**

I would be very much thankful if someone could come up with some suggestions or solutions.
Also thanks to the viewers for their time.

Comment: modal is designed to be a "one open at a time" popup.  We use jquery overlay http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/ where you can set it to allow multiple overlays (so the first doesn't close when the second opens)

Comment: Hi Matt, I am trying the jquery layout in my context. But, I was wondering if there is any solution using UIKIT's modal itself. Thanx

Comment: I haven't worked with UIKIT before so I can't help you change it.  Just know when I have used the model property on popups in the past it doesn't allow multiples.  Good Luck!

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I am seeking the same.

Comment: @xdrone if the problem is modal, the better solution I found is to use bmodal. Check this http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/ .It's easy and simple to use.